# Google Sheets Copying and Pasting from one sheet to another based on cell value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working with code that I found researching my issue. I've posted it below. The issue I'm having is that the date an item is returned is naturally going to change as the week progresses. I'm at a loss as to how I would alter the code to copy and paste the row if any combination of "Returned (date)" is input into column 8.

```
function onEdit() {
    // moves a row from a sheet to another when a magic value is entered in a column
    // adjust the following variables to fit your needs
    // see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/ehoCZjFPBao/discussion
    var sheetNameToWatch = "Checked Out";
    var columnNumberToWatch = 8; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
    var valueToWatch = "Returned 1/1";
    var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Returned";

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

    if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
        var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
        sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the [data operations](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/data) that was specified in the documentation?

Comment: Do you really want to do this `onEdit`, or would there be a function like `MATCH` or `QUERY` that would solve this for you?

What is the actual need? To be able to copy and paste, or to populate one sheet based on the data in another sheet, keeping them in sync with one another?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Google Sheets formula called ISDATE() you could just add a helper column that checks whether the input date is valid. Then just check the return value of this cell is TRUE